# Facebook Graph API (How to get user gender?)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on PHP project. I have to get id, fullname, firstname, gender and email of the user. I got id of the user. So, It is clear that there is no any problem in PHP facebook-sdk or Facebook library. But I can not get other fields. So, ther is something is wrong in my code. But I can't find that wrong code. If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You. Here is my code. Here is my code.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();

// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

$fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');         // To Get Facebook ID

echo $fbid;    //working as I'm getting facebook ID

$filenameIn = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/fields=gender';
$gender = file_get_contents($filenameIn);
echo $gender;    //I can not get this.
```

Comment: Hint: You should ask for the permission to get the information..

Comment: @Kamal.. Thanx.. Because I also have the same doubt that may be here I'm wrong. But I don't know that how to ask for the permissions. Can you explain with example or suggest me some link to overview.

Comment: `gender` doesn’t need an extra permission, it is included in public profile. But you are asking for the field in the wrong way here – `fields` is a _query string_ parameter, but you have just made it part of the _path_ component of the URL instead. And you don’t need to make an extra request here to get the id – just request `/me`, and specify all the fields you want in that call directly.

Comment: And you should not use `file_get_contents` here – you are aldready using the PHP SDK, so why make requests “bypassing” it using a completely different technique? Plus, `file_get_contents` doesn’t show you the response body by default, if the status code indicates an error … and with your wrong request you would have gotten one, but you didn’t see it – _because_ you used `file_get_contents`, instead of the SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CBroe is right. I have made that mistake. As I changed my code as CBroe has suggested, I got problem Solved. Here is correct code.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,gender');
$response = $request->execute();

// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

$fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');         // To Get Facebook ID
$fbgender = $graphObject->getProperty('gender'); // To Get Facebook gender

echo $fbid;    //working as I'm getting facebook ID
echo $fbgender;//working as I'm getting facebook gender
```

Comment: You can cut this code down further by doing: `$graphObject = $request->execute()->getGraphObject();`